# Querying a Sesame triplestore using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, maps, sesame

I am trying to find out if one can query a graph in Sesame triplestore using JavaScript and extract the result as SPARQL/JSON. I want to extract Lat/Long values and plot on a map using leaflet.js.

The follow up question is at [Querying Sesame triplestore using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785633/querying-sesame-triplestore-using-javascript?noredirect=1#comment47701245_29785633)

Comment: You have changed what your question is now, and the accepted answer no longer makes sense - please don't do this. It's fine to add additional information to _clarify_ a question, but if you have a different (followup) question, please post it _as a new question_ (linking back to the original question if necessary).

Comment: I have updated my answer this time around though, it's not _that_ much of a stretch after all :)  

Just saying that it's something to do differently in the future, perhaps.

Comment: Oh dear. We seem to be crossing streams here - you were editing your question while I was answering it at the same time! I will wait a bit to see how you want to sort this out.

Comment: Yeah! Thank you for helping out, Jeen. I'm still trying to get a hang of the rules here. The updated question is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785633/querying-sesame-triplestore-using-javascript. I have a new error with the fix you suggested. I'll post it after your response there. My gratitude for being so accommodating :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Sesame has a [REST API](http://rdf4j.org/sesame/2.8/docs/system.docbook?view#The_Sesame_Server_REST_API) which you can access from JavaScript, and you can request results in multiple formats (including SPARQL/JSON).